# C# Datagrid refresh

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to write a program with C# WPF and MySQL. I have two forms. In `form1`, there is a `DataGrid` where I can see my table content (with select) from the MySQL database and it works fine. In `form2` I can add something to my database (with insert) and this works fine as well.

When I start the program and list the content first and then click on `add player` (`form2` opens up) and I add a player, it doesn't appear on the `DataGrid` first, I always have to close the program first and then start it again to see the added player on the `DataGrid`.

I hope you guys know what I mean. I really need an answer and I really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you binding to an collection that inherits from ObservableCollection?  Doing this will ensure that the DataGrid recognises updates to the collection.

Comment: Please don't tag as `C` and `C#` unless you really use both languages. And in WPF, Forms don't exist. Are you talking about separate windows?

Comment: Another thing you could check is that the property you are binding the grid's ItemsSource to is a Dependency Property or implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  That way, if you change the change this property (ie Model.Items = [new select from database]) the view will recognise that the property has changed and update your DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `reload` the data into the `DataGridView`.
For example :

```
addPlayer addPlayer = new addPlayer();
private void addBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 
     addPlayer.ShowDialog();
     this.playersTBLTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataBaseDataSet.playersTBL);
 }
```

The key bit of code here is this line:

```
this.playersTBLTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataBaseDataSet.playersTBL);
```

It will `reload` your `DataGridView` data when you close the "Add Player" form.
Assuming you are using Table Adapters.

Answer (score 0):

use `datagridView1.Refresh();`

Refresh the datagridview that you expect to see the change in, Also keep in mind that the DataTable for that gridview also needs to be updated.

It would be a good idea after the addplayer click event to reload the datatable for the gridview and then refresh the datagrid.